# controller parameter : specific or generic

Tags: c#, api, parameters, architecture

Considering the following situation:
I want to update multiple field of an user (firstname, lastname, age, ...)

Using RESTFUL API

```
PUT /user/{userId}
```

In C# I will have the following method

```
UpdateUser(int userId, User user)
```

The issue is that User class may contains lot of parameter that will never change (like for example id, email, role, affiliation, registrationDate, ...)

So in swagger or in api description, is sometimes hard to know which are the required/optional parameter, and the description of the api get longer and longer since the User object may contains lot of field that is not important for this Update operation.

To solve this issue, I can create a specific "UpdateUserParameters" object that contains only required fields. The issue is if I do that for every api, then I will end with lot of different object that *in fine* represent everytime a subpart of an User.

I can also of course specify the important parameters in comments part of the api even if is less visible than the first solution for developer (speaking of which, swagger will put the whole User object definition and this can be disturbing.

So what's the best practice to deal with this issue?